# "Whole" vs "Entire"

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible to use 'whole' instead of 'entire' in the sentence below?
Actually I need to know if they both convey the same sense here or not and make sure if it sounds awkward or normal to native ears:

> - I have devoted my entire life to studying.

Comment: native *ears* instead of native *years*? I cannot make such a small edit

Comment: @malarres thank you for pointing out; it was a typo ;)

Comment: In both of cases, there are a lot of results which are provided by Google

Comment: Actually I need to know the most natural one @RongNguyen ;)

Comment: I personally think there's not much difference between the two (as used in the given example). It's likely on usage preference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. 
Both sentences sound just fine and both convey the same meaning.

The only difference to me is that the word "entire" gives the sentence a slightly more formal sound than "whole."